# How do I create a reusable custom control and use it in storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode

First of all, I have search google and stackoverflow for many hours, saw many similar question but none of their answers satisfy me.
I'm new to iOS developer. I have following question:
1. How do I create a reusable custom control?
2. How can I use it in storyboard (iOS4)?
3. How can I add custom control to Object library
4. Using custom control is recommend or not?

Thank in advance, any document link/help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Subclass the appropriate control
2. I typically drag and drop the "closest" control to what I need. For example, if I subclass `UIButton`, I'd use a `UIButton`. Then in the properties I'd switch the class from `UIButton` to my custom class. Incidentally, I assume you really mean iOS 5; you can't use Storyboards with iOS 4 and below
3. I'm not sure that you can
4. If none of the built-in controls do what you need to then sure

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any example?